# Why public IPv4 address range is different from private IPv4 address

Tags: networking

Why there are dedicated ranges of private IP addresses, What will happen if I use a public IP address range for my private n/w, it should not cause any conflict, because that is part of my private network and I will still use my assigned public IP address to communicate to the Internet ? today also multiple private networks use same range of private IPs maybe, then why not public IP range ?

I think I am missing some point. But lets say my public IP is A, and I have one device's private IP as B, now NAT contains the mapping of A - B, now lets say I try to send a request to a server having public IP B, what would be the difficulty here, In my mind, NAT would translate B to A, and send the request to public server with IP B and the sender's IP will be A, now when response comes, NAT will translate public IP A to Private IP B, what will the issue here ?

Comment: Good luck getting your routers to cooperate with your scheme.  People all over the world can share private IP addresses because they are private and there's no conflict.  Public IP addresses have to be unique so that the source of the transmission can be identified.  The source needs to be identified so that the reply is processed by the proper router.  You're probably too young to remember when people had to share public telephone numbers.  They were called party lines.  Your phone would ring, and the call would probably be for one of the other parties on the party line.

Comment: Because otherwise they would be the same and there would be no public and private about it, and everybody's internal IP addresses would conflict with everybody else's, and those with conflicting internal IP addresses would never be able to communicate with the public IP addresses of the same value. Some organizations went through exactly this issue in 1989-90 when the Internet went public, and they had to change all their internal addresses, at some sharp but very temporary pain. Don't be 30 years behind the times.

Comment: i think I am missing some point. But lets say my public IP is A, and I have one device's private IP as B, now NAT contains the mapping of A - B, now lets say I try to send a request to a server having public IP B, what would be the difficulty here, In my mind, NAT would translate B to A, and send the request to public server with IP B and the sender's IP will be A, now when response comes, NAT will translate public IP A to Private IP B, what will the issue here ?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc can you please clear the above doubt ?

Comment: Why would the NAT translate anything when the address is already to be found in the local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will happen if I use a public IP address range for my private n/w

Well, simple: you will not be able to reach anything on those public addresses from your private network. THAT IS IT.

Basically: if you i.e. use the addresses that resolve to www.stackoverflow.come, your internal servers get all internal requests for www.stackoverflow.com and you can not reach www.stackoverflow.com anymore.

THAT IS ALL THAT HAPPENS.

This totally does not matter (i.e. if you grab IP Addresses that are used by some far away ISP to dynamically hand out to their clients) because you never try to reach them, or it can result in some major site not being reachable. Totally random.

The idea of private addresses is not to stop you from using them, it is to make sure there is no overlap and companies do not need to ask for the (limited and out of addresses) public space without the risk of using an address that may be relevant.